# Delta exporting data in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, export

I need to implement a delta export functionality for an existing rails app. Delta export means that all data gets exported only once. E.g. I export all data today, when I export again tomorrow, only new data after the last export will be exported.

Is there a gem or generally a nice solution to do this?

My only approach so far is to store time of the last export somewhere and export all new data after the last export time. However, creating a table for one single field and row seems a bit weird to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain what data you are talking about, and what you mean by exporting it?  Do you mean for example an SQL dump, or what?  Also when you say "new data" do you mean "changed data", ie "new or updated records"?  If it's updated do you want to export the whole lot or just the changes?  etc

Comment: If you did create a table it wouldn't have one row - it would have one row for *every time you'd done an export*.

Comment: I mean an export to a CSV file which is to be imported to another system. Orders will be exported which do not change after they were created hence only new data.

Comment: I would do a table called data_exports with a datetime field and a rake task which only gets records where updated_at > the time of the last export.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Will do that. If you put this into an answer, you'll even get an "accept answer" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a table like so:

```
create_table :data_exports do |t|
  t.datetime :exported_at
end
```

with a corresponding DataExport model.

Then i would make a rake task which

a) exports all records from the required tables, with a condition like `where(["updated_at > ?", DataExport.last.exported_at])`

b) does DataExport.create(:exported_at => Time.now)